# In what significant ways would the Prophet that was to come be similar to Moses? Deut 18:15

Tags: word-study, deuteronomy, moses

> Deuteronomy 18:15 (NKJV)
>
> " The LORD your God will raise up for you a
>   **Prophet like me** from your 
>   midst, from your brethren. Him you shall hear

1) According to this passage, in what ways was the Prophet supposed to "be like" or be "similar" to Moses in order to help the Jews to accurately identify him? 
What similarities did Moses have in mind?

2) What are the key events, qualities and aspects  of Moses as a man and as a prophet that must exist in the life of the Prophet that was to come.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently did a paper on this subject.

There are a few points to discern first: The biggest of which is the decision regarding single or multiple referents.  Was their only one person who was the fulfillment of the prophecy or multiple people who fulfilled the prophecy with one ultimate fulfillment.  I come down on the side of only one referent--that the Messiah and only the Messiah would be the fulfillment.

Since this is a hermeneutics site the other issue is how does one find the links.  Many writers have suggested numerous similarities between the two in sometimes long lists of similarities.  That is the method the medieval Jewish commentators used to show Jesus was not the fulfillment of the Deuteronomy prophecy.

What is helpful is the four explicit statements found in the Deuteronomy passage (with verse 18-19 being a summary restatement):

1. He was to be a prophet (V.15)
2. He was to be an Israelite -- a son of Isaac and Jacob (V. 15)
3. He will be a lawgiver that is like Moses.  The "unto him shall ye hearken" of the KJV.  The Hebrew verb word certainly carries the primary idea of listening.  It also carries the idea of obeying in some of its other uses within the book of Deuteronomy.  Yoo-Hee Kim wrote an excellent dissertation called "Deut 18:15-22 reexamined within the context of the Pentateuch and in light of the final shape of the TaNaK," in which she argues that this verb, as it is used in Deuteronomy, suggests that the prophet will be speaking with an authority equal with YHWH.  The Later prophets spoke on behalf of God so they would not have fulfilled this aspect.  Whereas Jesus spoke as equal with God thereby fulfilling this aspect.
4. The language of verses 16-17 points back to Deut 5 and the events at Horeb (which is another name for Sinai).  The people of Israel had been afraid of a direct face to face encounter with God and since Moses has survived they asked God if he could be their mediator.  In Deut. 18 the idea is that the person who fulfills the prophecy would be a mediator between God and man.  This too excludes the other Old Testament prophets since they were only speaking on behalf of God and not acting as a mediator.  Jesus was the first person to act as a mediator between God and man, following Moses.

In Deut. 33-34 there is one additional idea that is explicitly stated.  The prophet would speak face to face with God, which implies He would do so and live.  Also depending on the date of authorship one holds, this might suggest that it was written much later in Israel's history thereby also excluding the other prophets (Deut. 34:10).

Comment: Ken banks I don't know what to say. This is a brilliant answer you've given. Can you give me a link to your paper on this subject?

Comment: I was running very late in submitting it and so I didn't do the normal edits one would do before turning it in.  It has a lot of grammar mistakes and I would want to fix all of those before I put it out for public consumption.  I only needed a 75 out of a 100 to get an A in the class so I didn't bother cleaning it up.  Maybe over the weekend so I can post it to Academia.com where I have posted a couple of my PhD papers.

Comment: Ok. Whenever it's ready let me know. I hope you won't forget.

Comment: Did you ever post your paper?

Comment: I just posted it on Academia.edu -- the title is A Greater Moses Deuteronomy 18:15-20.  The link is https://www.academia.edu/35862083/A_Greater_Moses_Deuteronomy_18_15-20

Answer (score 5):

| Similarity | Moses | Jesus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Descendant of Jacob | Exodus 2:1-2 | Matthew 1:1-16; Luke 3:23-38 |
| Hunted by a king at birth | Exodus 1:15-2:10 | Matthew 2:13-23 |
| Son of a king (adopted) | Exodus 2:10 | Matthew 1:18-25, 16:16 |
| Sojourned in Egypt | Exodus 1:1-14, 2:11-15 | Matthew 2:13-15 |
| Shepherd | Exodus 3:1-10 | John 10:1-18 |
| Orchestrated the Passover | Exodus 12:1-14 | Matthew 26:17-30 |
| Led Israel out of slavery | Exodus 12:29-42 | Luke 4:18-19, John 8:34-36 |
| Baptized | Exodus 14:16-22 | Matthew 3:13-17 |
| Spent 40 years in the wilderness | Exodus 14:33-34 | Matthew 4:1-2 |
| Authority was challenged by jealous priests | Numbers 12:1-2 | Matthew 21:23-27, John 5:16-18, 8:53-58 |
| Mediated a covenant between God and man | Exodus 24:1-18 | Matthew 26:26-29, Mark 14:22-25, Luke 22:14-20 |
| Law keeper/giver/teacher | Exodus 20:1-17 | Matthew 5:17-20 |
| Performed miracles | Exodus 14:21-31, 15:25 | John 2:1-11, 4:46-54 |
| Intimate relationship with God | Exodus 33:11 | John 1:1-18, 10:30 |
| Interceded between God and Israel, to the point of sacrificing his life | Exodus 32:30-32 | Romans 5:6-11, Hebrews 9:11-28 |
| Body's location is unknown | Deuteronomy 34:6 | Acts 1:9-11 |
| Rejected by Israel | Exodus 2:14-15, 32:1-10 | Matthew 23:37-39, John 1:11, 7:3-5, 12:39-40 |

I'll end with John 5:45-47:

> “But do not think I will accuse you before the Father. Your accuser is Moses, on whom your hopes are set. If you believed Moses, you would believe me, for he wrote about me. But since you do not believe what he wrote, how are you going to believe what I say?”

Comment: Was also hunted by a king at birth. +1

Comment: They both wore sandals.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** - To remove Strong's numbers as they were unhelpful.

> **Deut. 18:18**  -  I will raise them up a Prophet from among, their brethren, like unto thee, **and
> will put my words in his mouth;** and he shall
> speak unto them all that I shall
> command him.

---

The coming prophet was first a minister (disciple?) of Moses:

> **Exo. 24:13**  -  And Moses rose up, and his minister Joshua: and Moses went up into
> the mount of God.
>
> **Josh. 3:7**  -  And the LORD said unto Joshua, This day will I begin to magnify thee in the
> sight of all Israel, that **they may know
> that, as I was with Moses,  I will
> be with thee.**

**Similarities of Moses and Joshua:**

1. Both were from Jacob's house. Moses was a Levite, and Joshua from Joseph's tribe, Ephraim, which was adopted by Jacob as his own.

> **Exo. 2:1**  -  And there went a man of the house, of Levi, and took   a
> daughter of Levi.
>
> **Exo. 2:2**  -  And the woman conceived, and bore a son **[Moses]**: and when she saw him that he
>   goodly , she hid him three
> months.
>
> **Num. 13:8**  -  Of the tribe) of Ephraim, **Oshea [eusho-Hosea]** the son of Nun.

2. Joshua was made holy like Moses when Moses put his hands upon Joshua per Yahweh's instruction.

> **Num. 27:18**  -  And the LORD said unto Moses, Take thee Joshua the son of Nun, a
> man in whom  the spirit, and lay thine
> hand upon him;

3. Like Moses, Joshua will lead the Israelites.

> **Num. 27:20**  -  And thou [Moses] shalt put  of thine honor,  upon him [Joshua], that all the
> congregation of the children of Israel may be
> obedient.

4. Like Moses, the Lord fights for Joshua.

> **Deut. 3:21**  -  And I commanded Joshua at that time, saying, Thine eyes have seen
> all that the LORD your God hath done unto
> these two kings: so shall the LORD
> do unto all the kingdoms whither,
> thou passest.
>
> **Deut. 3:22**  -  Ye shall not fear them: for the LORD your God he shall fight for you.

5. The protections of Yahweh to Moses, became also true for Joshua.

> **Deut. 3:28**  -  But charge Joshua, and encourage him, and strengthen him: for he shall
> go over before this people, and he shall
> cause them to inherit the land which thou shalt
> see.
>
> **Deut. 31:7**  -  And Moses called unto Joshua, and said unto him in the sight of all Israel,
> Be strong and of a good courage: for thou must
> go with this people unto the land
> which the LORD hath sworn unto their fathers to
> give them; and thou shalt cause them to inherit it.
>
> **Deut. 31:8**  -  **And the LORD, he   that doth go before thee; he will be with thee, he
> will not fail thee, neither forsake thee:
> fear not, neither be dismayed.**
>
> **Josh. 3:7**  -  And the LORD said unto Joshua, This day will I begin to magnify thee in the
> sight of all Israel,) that they may know
> that, as I was with Moses,  I will
> be with thee.

6. A stark difference between Moses and Joshua, to me, is:

> **Deut. 34:10**  -  **And there arose not a prophet since in Israel like unto Moses, whom the
> LORD knew face to face,**

-- Other verses make it sound like Joshua was with Moses when Moses was speaking f2f with Yahweh; however, perhaps Joshua was only a witness.

> **Exo. 24:13**  -  **And Moses rose up, and his minister Joshua: and Moses went up into
> the mount of God.**
>
> **Exo. 24:14**  -  And he said unto the elders, Tarry ye here for us, until, we come
> again unto you: and, behold, Aaron and Hur
>  with you: if any man have any matters to
> do, let him come unto them.
>
> **Exo. 33:8**  -  And it came to pass, **when Moses went out unto the tabernacle**,  all the
> people rose up, and stood every man  his
> tent door, and looked after Moses,
> until he was gone into the tabernacle.
>
> **Exo. 33:9**  -  And it came to pass, **as Moses entered into the tabernacle, the cloudy pillar
> descended, and stood  the door of the
> tabernacle, and   talked with
> Moses.**
>
> **Exo. 33:10**  -  And all the people saw the cloudy pillar stand  the tabernacle
> door: and all the people rose up and
> worshiped, every man  his tent door.
>
> **Exo. 33:11**  -  And the LORD spoke unto Moses face to face, as a man
> speaketh unto his friend. And he turned again
> into the camp: but his servant **Joshua, the
> son of Nun, a young man, **departed not
> out of the tabernacle.**

Comment: Thanks tblue. +1. But this answer needs a lot of editing. Put your scripture quotations in quote blocks and remove those numbers beside the texts. Not useful.

Comment: I have just noticed this post, albeit old i thought i make a comment.  Joshus as ruled out based on Deu 34:10 and the prophecy relates to one to come.  Also cannot relate to Jesus, unlike - Jesus is God / son of God not prophet, miracle birth, Moses made laws, never married or had children, Moses had a natural death & normal burial, Jesus rejected Moses accepted, Jesus did not emigrate,   Jesus resurrected and many more...

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no clear answer from the verse itself, or even the surrounding context.

[Rashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi) skirts the problem by saying that "like me" modifies "from your midst" and "from your brethren". That is, God will raise you up a prophet from your brethren in your midst in the same way that I, Moses, am one of your brethren in your midst.

The [Ramban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachmanides) continues that "from your brethren" and "from your midst" means not a foreigner and not even a son of Jacob resident of the diaspora.

[Rabenu B'Chayeh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahya_ben_Asher) continues this logic and says that "like me", "from your brethren" means a son of Jacob rather than a son of Esau or Ishamel, who are also called "brethren" (e.g. Numbers 20:14).

The [Ibn Ezra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ibn_Ezra) and the [Rashbam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashbam) says that "like me" means that the prophet is a prophet of God, YHVH, and follows in the way of Moses regarding adherence to the commandments, and not a prophet of some other god or religion.

The Ramban says, based on Exodus 15:30-31, that the prophet must work some *signs* (although not necessarily *miracles* in the modern understanding of the term), as did Moses and Aaron.

We have a working example, as to what Moses intended, appointed by Moses himself, in the person of Joshua.

The distinguishing features of Moses, Joshua, the Judges and Samuel, is that they were all recognized and accepted national leaders in their lifetimes and not voices crying in the wilderness, or leaders of some fringe movement.<sup>1</sup> None of them were anointed, and none of them were priests.

---

<sup>1. Not that their leadership of any of these prophet leaders was unchallenged, but it was never outright rejected by the nation. They were never deposed, sent into exile, or even killed in battle or murdered.</sup>

Comment: Thanks. But since Moses was persecuted several times by the murmurings and grumblings of the congregation, doesn't it indicate that this leader would himself be persecuted. They tried to stone Moses and Aaron at different times. At times they rejected the divine appointment of Moses as their leader. I brought this up because of the second to the last paragraph in your answer. +1

Comment: Even Samuel, the Judges and other prophets felt rejected by the community. So I believe that a challenge with Jewish acceptance should also be included in your answer.

Comment: That Prophet should encounter rejection from the leadership just like Moses and other prophets experienced.

Comment: @user20490 I rewrote slightly to address your concerns. Moses's leadership was seriously challenged several times, but never rejected. He appointed his own successor, and died while still the leader of the nation, like Joshua, most of the Judges and Samuel.

Comment: Daniel 9:26 says that Meshiach will be cut off but not for himself. Moreover many prophets were killed and murdered by the people. I also want to disagree with Ramban because Moses was chosen while in the diaspora. He lived both as an Egyptian and later as a Midianite. The name of his first son "Gershom" proves that he was in the diaspora.

Comment: @user20490 The book of Daniel is a post exilic "historical" scroll that was not included in the books of the prophets and like Ezekiel, has no bearing on what was written by Moses. The mashiah of Daniel is not the prophet of Deuteronomy 18:15, it is a later concept, the secular leader who is the anointed son of David. Many true prophets were indeed murdered but Deuteronomy 18:15 is talking about a different sort of promise, that of Joshua, Deborah, and Samuel. None of these people were anointed.

Comment: Does it mean that the prophet and the Messiah are two different people entirely.

Comment: @user20490 From the time of Moses until Saul the only mashiah is the chief priest who was anointed with olive oil. Saul was the first king who was mashiah, anointed. Second temple chief priests were also mashiah, anointed, but with persimmon oil. It is only late in the first century that mashiah son of David becomes Mashiah and then MASHIAH. Historically, the concept underwent a transformation and inflation, first in Judaism and consequently in Christianity. So the prophet of Deuteronomy 18:15 is a figure like Moses, Joshua or Samuel, a non-anointed leader who does his work then passes on.

Comment: So the Prophet and the Meshiach are two different individuals right?  According to Psalm 99:3, Moses and Aaron were both priests. So by implication this prophet would also have to be a Priest like Moses was isn't it.

Comment: The whole thing is mind boggling.

Comment: @user20490 As Abu Minir wrote, the traditional Jewish understanding of Deuteronomy 18:15 is that there will be future prophets that will guide the Jewish people and convey to them the word of G-d like Moses did. It does not mean that their life story or character will be similar to Moses.  The context which contrasts the Israelites listening to prophets with the Canaanites listening to necromancers and describes the false prophet, indicate that these verses are not referring to a particular prophet of the future but future prophets generally.

Comment: @conceptualinertia Nope. The discourse between John the Baptist and the servants of the temple priests proved that Deut 18:15 was also referring to a specific individual called the Prophet. The word prophet is capitalized in Deuteronomy and in the discourse of the Pharisees with John the Baptist.

Comment: Just like there are antichrists and an Antichrist so are there prophets and a Prophet. I wish I could explain it to you in more detail but typing on a phone is very inconvenient.

Comment: @user20490 I do not see how that discourse proves anything about Deut 18:15. Even if there are prophets and the Prophet, Deutoronomy 18:15 is referring to prophets. It is describing all of the future genuine prophets that would guide Israel in the coming generations. Maybe there was a tradition of a the Prophet at the time of John the Baptist, or maybe it is mistranslation or mistaken transmission where it was originally a prophet, and became the Prophet.